# Filtering JMESPath with contains

Tags: json, filter, filtering, jmespath

JMESPath is a query language for JSON, used by Azure.

Using its own example given from http://jmespath.org/

```
{
  "locations": [
    {"name": "Seattle", "state": "WA"},
    {"name": "New York", "state": "NY"},
    {"name": "Bellevue", "state": "WA"},
    {"name": "Olympia", "state": "WA"}
  ]
}
```

How to list all locations whose name contains a letter `"l"`, or a string `"le"`? thx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Filtering by character and by string works the same.

---

### query locations w/ names containing `"l"`

```
locations[?name.contains(@, `l`)]
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Seattle",
    "state": "WA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bellevue",
    "state": "WA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Olympia",
    "state": "WA"
  }
]
```

---

### query locations w/ names containing `"le"`

```
locations[?name.contains(@, `le`)]
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Seattle",
    "state": "WA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bellevue",
    "state": "WA"
  }
]
```

---

### query locations w/ names containing either `"ue"` or `"ia"`

```
locations[?name.contains(@, `ue`) || name.contains(@, `ia`)]
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Bellevue",
    "state": "WA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Olympia",
    "state": "WA"
  }
]
```