# Filter elements containing string with JMESPath

Tags: ansible, jmespath, json-query

I want to get a list of addresses of a defined interface type.
I found some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774937/filtering-jmespath).

Here is my playbook:

```yaml
- name: Test JMESPath
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    interfaces:
    - name: em0
      address: 10.127.37.89/29
    - name: bge0
      address: 10.112.171.81/28
    - name: bge1
      address: 10.112.171.65/28
    - name: bge2
      address: 10.112.171.97/28
  tasks:
    - name: JMESPath query
      set_fact:
        result: "{{ interfaces | json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?name.contains(@, 'bge')].address"

    - debug:
        var: result
```

I'd like to get:

```json
[
  "10.112.171.81/28",
  "10.112.171.65/28",
  "10.112.171.97/28"
]
```

It works on JMESPath website, but my playbook fails :

> ```
> ansible-playbook play-testJMESPath.yml [WARNING]: provided hosts list
> is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit
> localhost does not match 'all'
>
> PLAY [Test JMESPath]
> **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
>
> TASK [JMESPath query]
> ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************* fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "JMESPathError in json_query
> filter plugin:\nIn function contains(), invalid type for value:
> external, expected one of: ['array', 'string'], received:
> \"unknown\""}
>
> PLAY RECAP
> ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0   
> failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
> ```

Could someone explain me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the JMESPath issue you are seeing, this is explained here:

> The problem is related to the fact that Ansible uses own types for strings: `AnsibleUnicode` and `AnsibleUnsafeText`.
> And as long as jmespath library has very strict type-checking, it fails to accept this types as string literals.

<sup>*Source: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299#issuecomment-331068246*</sup>

---

The **trick** to make it work, as explained in the same issue, is to use a `to_json | from_json` filter pair, in order to force back the right type.

So, the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ interfaces | to_json | from_json | json_query(query) }}"
  vars:
    query: "[?name.contains(@, 'bge')].address"
    interfaces:
      - name: em0
        address: 10.127.37.89/29
      - name: bge0
        address: 10.112.171.81/28
      - name: bge1
        address: 10.112.171.65/28
      - name: bge2
        address: 10.112.171.97/28
```

Gives the expected:

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - 10.112.171.81/28
  - 10.112.171.65/28
  - 10.112.171.97/28
```

Answer (score 3):

[Jinja filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters) can use [Python regex tests](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings). This makes them a stronger tool compared to [JMESPath contains function](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#contains) which only *" returns true if the string contains the provided $search argument"*.

The tasks below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ interfaces|
                    selectattr('name', 'search', 'bge')|
                    map(attribute='address')|
                    list }}"
    - debug:
        var: result
```

give

```yaml
    "result": [
        "10.112.171.81/28",
        "10.112.171.65/28",
        "10.112.171.97/28"
    ]
```

Comment: good, you can also use the match attribute of selectattr:  ``` "{{ interfaces | selectattr('name', 'match', '^bge') | map(attribute='address')| list }}" ```

Comment: Thank you, this might come in handy