# Create list of dict filtering different value with Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, jmespath

I'm looking for a better solution to filter a list of dicts by a key A and return a list of value of key B. To be more concrete - every host has a dict:

```
infrastructure:
  name: "x..."
network:
  address: "1..."
```

There are hosts, where `network.address` is defined and there are hosts, where `network.address` is not defined. I need now a list of all `infrastructure.name` with defined `network.address`.

```
- name: "Define Alias fact"
  set_fact:
    alias: []

- name: "Add Aliases for all hosts with network.address is defined"
  set_fact:
    alias: "{{ alias + [hostvars[host].infrastructure.name + '-alias'] }}"
  when:
    - "hostvars[host].network is defined"
    - "hostvars[host].network.address is defined"
  with_items: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: host
```

That works, but is a little bit messy, because I call set_fact many times and add items to a list.

When I have a look at:

```
- name: "Define addresses fact"
  set_fact:
    address: "{{ groups['all'] | map('extract', hostvars) | list | json_query('[*].network.address') }}"
```

This is much shorter, maybe easier.

I'd like to ask, if I can use `map` and `extract` and the "list of dicts" before flatten the list to "filter out" all items where network.address is not defined and use json_query together with some string operation to append the '-alias'. Is there a similar easy way to replace the first script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a pure JMESPath way, given the JSON

```
[
  {
    "infrastructure": {"name": "x..."},
    "network": {"address": "1..."}
  },
  {
    "infrastructure": {"name": "y..."}
  },
  {
    "infrastructure": {"name": "z..."},
    "network": {"address": "2..."}
  },
  {
    "infrastructure": {"name": "a..."},
    "network": {}
  }
]
```

You can extract the `infrastructure.name` concatenated with `-alias` having a `network.address` set this way:

```
[?network.address].join('-', [infrastructure.name, 'alias'])
```

This will yield:

```json
[
  "x...-alias",
  "z...-alias"
]
```

The function [`join`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#join) is primarily meant to glue array elements together, but it can also be used to concatenate string.

---

And so for a playbook demonstrating this:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: >-
          {{ 
            servers | to_json | from_json | 
            json_query(
              '[?network.address].join(`-`, [infrastructure.name, `alias`])'
            ) 
          }}
      vars:
        servers:
          - infrastructure:
              name: x...
            network:
              address: 1...
          - infrastructure:
              name: y...
          - infrastructure:
              name: z...
            network:
              address: 2...
          - infrastructure:
              name: a...
            network:
```

<sup>*Note that the odd construct `| from_json | to_json` is explained [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65096465/2123530)*</sup>

This yields:

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "x...-alias",
        "z...-alias"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: In my case the "server" dict is part of hostvars and it looks, I don't need to filter thru `| to_json | from_json` but it works as expected.

Comment: Ah yes indeed, this is an issue with YAML/Ansible data, if you have this as a fact from a previous task/host, then you should be good without it