# extract data with json_query from jinja2 variable in ansible

Tags: ansible, jmespath

I have a variable in the inventory that contains a JSON formatted data.

I want to extract a specific part of the data with `json_query`.

The variable contains a list of domains with related IP addresses (the JSON is valid):

```
DOMAIN={"domain1.net": {"addr": ["10.10.10.10", "10.10.10.20"]}, "domain2.net": {"addr": ["172.16.10.1", "172.16.20.1", "172.16.30.1"]}}
```

With an ansible-playbook, using `json_query`, I want to extact only the `domain2.net` IP addresses.

I've used https://api.gopipeline.io/jmespath-tester to validate the JMESPath query.

With this filter: `"domain2.net".addr` in the jmespath-tester, I got the following (expected) output:

```json
[
  "172.16.10.1",
  "172.16.20.1",
  "172.16.30.1"
]
```

When I apply the same json_query with this ansible-playbook, I have no output:

Task

```yaml
 ---                                                                                      
 - name: Extract addr for domain2.net              
   tags: test                                                                            
   debug: msg="{{ DOMAIN | to_json | from_json | json_query("domain2.net".addr) }}"
```

Output:

```
ok: [domain-lab-1] => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

I've tested also another query, by filtering only `domain2.net` in JMESPath online tester:
https://api.gopipeline.io/jmespath-tester and I get this **expected output**:

```json
{
  "addr": [
    "172.16.10.1",
    "172.16.20.1",
    "172.16.30.1"
  ]
}
```

But, when I try to do the same within an Ansible playbook, still no output:
Task

```yaml
 ---                                                                                      
 - name: Extract addr for domain2.net              
   tags: test                                                                            
   debug: msg="{{ DOMAIN | to_json | from_json | json_query("domain2.net") }}"
```

Output:

```
ok: [domain-lab-1] => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

If I try to print only the `DOMAIN` var, I can see the whole JSON output.
So, the variable is correctly read.

I'm using ansible 2.9.14.

I've read that the `to json|from json` from here:

[Ansible : filter elements containing string with JMESPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65094976/ansible-filter-elements-containing-string-with-jmespath)

I'm not sure if is needed in my case, anyway adding or removing them does not make any difference.

Comment: Typo related to quotes and escaping => `msg="{{ DOMAIN | to_json | from_json | json_query('\"domain2.net\".addr') }}"`. But that is really using a Caterpillar to dig a hole for a single seed => `"{{ DOMAIN['domain2.net'].addr }}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need *json_query*. Simply reference the attribute. You can't use the dot notation because the attribute *domain2.net* is not a valid name of the variable in Ansible. Put it into the brackets instead. For example

```yaml
    - name: Extract addr for domain2.net
      debug:
        msg: "{{ DOMAIN['domain2.net'].addr }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - 172.16.10.1
  - 172.16.20.1
  - 172.16.30.1
```

**Notes**

- See [Referencing key:value dictionary variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables).
- Any string is a valid key in the [YAML dictionary(mapping)](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#3211-nodes).
- [Ansible variable name](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names) can only include letters, numbers, and underscores.

Comment: Interesting. It works, thanks! Can you please elaborate what you mean with "domain2.net is not a valid ansible name"?

Comment: I added the notes.