# JMES Path "contains" missing argument in parameter list

Tags: azure-cli, jmespath

I'm attempting the following Azure CLI command and query from PowerShell:

> az account list-locations --query [?contains(name,"us")].[displayName,name]

Unfortunately the `--query` parameter gives me this error:

> Missing argument in parameter list

...and it points to the comma in the `contains` function.  That's a surreal error, since the `contains` function only takes two arguments...and both are present.  Furthermore, I have tested the above syntax in the [jmespath online](https://jmespath.org/) fiddle, where it works just fine.

In that online fiddle, I successfully used this expression:

> [?contains(state,'WA')].name | sort(@) | {WashingtonCities: join(', ', @)}

The data for the above sample, is as follows:

```json
[
    {"name": "Seattle", "state": "WA"},
    {"name": "New York", "state": "NY"},
    {"name": "Bellevue", "state": "WA"},
    {"name": "Olympia", "state": "WA"}
]
```

So what could possibly be wrong with `--query` that I'm passing to the Azure CLI?

I have also attempted this [alternate `contains` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774937/filtering-jmespath-with-contains) someone proposed, which also didn't work.

Comment: Just to be sure. Are you aware that the attribute `displayName` is missing in the dictionaries?

Comment: @VladimirBotka Not sure what you mean.  A simple `az account list-locations` command produces objects that all have the `displayName` property.

Comment: This is OK. I mean there are attributes `name` and `state` in the data for the above sample.

Answer (score 1):

Try back-ticks instead of double-quotes. See the examples of the function [*contains*](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#contains). The query below should return an empty list because none of the names contains `us`

```
[?contains(name, `us`)].[displayName,name]
```

For example,

```
[?contains(name, `ll`)].[displayName,name]
```

should return

```
[[nul, "Bellevue]"]
```

---

Python program for testing

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.9

import jmespath
import yaml


s = [{"name": "Seattle", "state": "WA"},
     {"name": "New York", "state": "NY"},
     {"name": "Bellevue", "state": "WA"},
     {"name": "Olympia", "state": "WA"}]

print(yaml.dump(s))

r = jmespath.search('[?contains(name, `us`)].[displayName,name]', s)
print(yaml.dump(r))

r = jmespath.search('[?contains(name, `ll`)].[displayName,name]', s)
print(yaml.dump(r))

r = jmespath.search('[?contains(state, `WA`)].name|sort(@)|{WA: join(`, `, @)}', s)
print(yaml.dump(r))
```

gives

```yaml
- name: Seattle
  state: WA
- name: New York
  state: NY
- name: Bellevue
  state: WA
- name: Olympia
  state: WA

[]

- - null
  - Bellevue

WA: Bellevue, Olympia, Seattle
```

Comment: What shell are you using?  I'm using PowerShell Core, and the use of back-ticks causes  PowerShell to prompt me with a `>>` continuation; That is, it is now expecting something additional.  If I simply hit `enter` at the continuation, then I'm given an error about a missing argument in the `contains` expression.

Comment: I'm using Bash. The execution of the Python script shouldn't depend on a shell.

Comment: Wow! Although I can't make this work in PowerShell, I just discovered I can make it work in the git bash shell, with this specific use of single-ticks and back-ticks: 
--query '[?contains(name,`us`)].[displayName,name]'.  Remember, I am exercising this JMESpath not from a program...but from a CLI environment by way of the Azure CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Testing in Azure Cloud Shell, the following syntax works in both Bash and PowerShell environments.

*az account list-locations --query "[?contains(name,'us')].[displayName,name]"*

Most Microsoft docs are written and tested for Bash so if you are working in a PowerShell environment, check out one of these docs for common differences:

- [Quoting issues with PowerShell](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/quoting-issues-with-powershell.md)
- [Use quotation marks in Azure CLI parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively?tabs=bash%2Cbash2#use-quotation-marks-in-parameters)
- Compare syntax of CMD, PowerShell and Bash in [Query command output using JMESPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?tabs=concepts%2Cbash)
- [Error handling for the Azure CLI in PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively?tabs=bash%2Cbash2#error-handling-for-azure-cli-in-powershell)